# Center logo in a min-width none responsive background

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I had to set a `min-width:1200px;` on a background image to stop it from resizing. How to make the logo on top of it stay responsive? it should stay in the middle of the screen, not affected by the fact that the background is no longer responsive.

So the parent div of the logo shouldn't be responsive, while the logo should stay responsive. I can't use any CSS framework, it's a WordPress site

Comment: would be great if you post a simplified version of you code where you reproduce the issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't wrap the `logo` inside another container and it's direct parent has `min-width:1200px`, you could use `position:fixed` on the `logo` and position it centered on the page.

Without any other code from you, here's the solution

```css
header {
  min-width:1200px;
  background:red;
  height:80px;
}
img {
  position:fixed;
  top:15px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%)
}
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
</header>
```

Comment: The problem with `position:fixed` is that when scrolling down, the logo scrolls down too

Comment: @Lynob that could be solved by some simple javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `flex` with  `justify-content: center` to align the logo in the center of your header.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width:1200px;
  background:red;
  height:80px;
}

img {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
</header>
```

or if you want your logo to be always in the center of your screen you could try

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 1200px;
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.image {
  position: 'fixed';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="image">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: as i understood, the OP wants the logo to be centered inside the page ( screen ) even if the `header` is wider than the screen.

Comment: The problem with `position:fixed` is that when scrolling down, the logo scrolls down too